# Graficar una imagen de un arreglo de dos dimensiones

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Estoy pasando una imagen a un arreglo unidimensional, Este lo debo pasar a otro arreglo de dos dimensiones del cual debo graficar la imagen guardada. la imagen tiene su inicio en `1078` y finaliza en `3078`, el problema que tengo es al graficar la imagen ya que esta se gráfica corrida. 
Esta es la funcion que tengo.

```
void pasoArreglo(FILE* Archivo) {

char datos[3078];
fread(datos, 1, 3078, Archivo);
char dimenciones[80][25];
for (int y = 0; y < 25; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 80; x++) {
        dimenciones[x][y] = datos[1078 + ((y * 2) + x)];
    }
}

char Rcolor = 0, Gcolor = 0, Bcolor = 0;

for (int y = 24; y >= 0; y--) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 80; x++) {

        if (dimenciones[x][y] & 0x1) { Rcolor = FOREGROUND_RED; }
        if (dimenciones[x][y] & 0x2) { Gcolor = FOREGROUND_GREEN; }
        if (dimenciones[x][y] & 0x4) { Bcolor = FOREGROUND_BLUE; }

        gotoxy(x, y);
        setColor(Rcolor | Gcolor | Bcolor);
        printf("%c", 219);



        Rcolor = 0;
        Gcolor = 0;
        Bcolor = 0;
    }       
  }
}
```

Comment: El formato de la imagen esta en BMP.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo eso del "(y * 2) + x"...no debería ser mas bien "(y * 80) + x"...o sea "y * ancho de la imagen en bytes + x"...no se si ese sera el problema pero espero pueda servir de ayuda...
Igual la multiplicación por 2 es porque cada color ocupa 2 bytes en lugar de 1...si es así supongo que el array se queda pequeño para una imagen de 80x25 pues 80x25 = 2000 bytes que son los que especificas en el enunciado de la pregunta (va de 1078 a 3078)...bueno..espero pueda servir de ayuda..

Comment: gracias, me sirvió mucho.

Answer (score -1):

```
Algoritmo matriz_1
    definir n,f,c Como Entero
    definir matriz Como Entero
    dimension matriz(10,10)
    escribir 'digite n'
    leer n 
    para f<-1 hasta n con paso 1 hacer
    para c<-1 hasta n con paso 1 hacer
        escribir 'ingrese celda ','',f,'-',c
        leer matriz(f,c)
        FinPara
    FinPara

    para f<-1 hasta n con paso 1 Hacer
        para c<-1 hasta n con paso 1 hacer
            escribir Sin Saltar matriz(f,c),' '
        FinPara
        escribir ' '
    FinPara
FinAlgoritmo
```

Comment: Creo que tu respuesta no tiene nada que ver con esta pregunta, más que nada porque la pregunta es sobre c++ y has puesto pseudocódigo.